# How to convert existing code to dependency on interfaces

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem, which I am encountering again and again in my code base. Let me try to explain.

Project A -- package x.y -- Class 1 (abstract class with lots of functionality already in it)
Project A -- package x.y.z.w -- Class 2 extends Class 1 (implements missing methods and uses lots of methods in Class 1 by calls to super)

I need to extract Class 2 into a separate project (Project B) with no dependency on Project A. Project A will still contain code that needs Project B to run, so there will be a dependency in that Project A will depend on Project B. 
Please keep in mind that code base is huge and I can't change anything in Class 1 as it is used absolutely everywhere and it is also very convoluted as it implements multiple interfaces, extends JPanel etc.

Dependency injection pattern won't work as I don't have a point of instantiation from where to inject the dependency.

I am really struggling to do this neatly. Any ideas/help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Without more details, it's impossible to help. All we know is that you have an inheritance relationship. There's no way you can inherit from a class without having the superclass in the dependencies.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of having interface based dependency but struggling to work out how to put the interfaces in place. Sorry for being vague. It is very complicated :(

Comment: Is it _your code_ in the codebase or something you inherited?

Comment: I think it is safe to say that I'd be infinitely embarrassed if this was my code. Inherited code for sure. I'm trying to clean it up

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, your goal is to:

```
Goal 1: Project A depends on Project B
Goal 2: Project B does NOT depend on Project A
```

Where your conditions are:

```
1: Class 1 in Project A
2: Class 2 in Project B extends Class 1
```

You can't inherit from a class you don't have on the classpath. A possible solution is to:

```
Step 1: Create a new abstract class Class3 in PackageB;
Step 2: Move all the code out of Class1 in it; and 
Step 3: Have both Class1 (still abstract) and Class2 extend it.
```

Correct me if I haven't understood your question correctly.